# "Equatorial" line small crack on the tire - is the tire damaged?

Tags: tires

I just found a weird small crack in the form of a line on my tires. I didn't see anything like that on the other pictures here. The line seems to go exactly where the car touches the surface. What do you think about that, is the tire damaged and needs immediate replacement or it's just a small thing?

It's, by the way, Nokian WR D4 tire, 4 years old (and this one is one of 4, one from 2 which are worn, around 4 mm, but the second pair has still around 7 and also have the identical cracks).

[image: ,]

Comment: Tire health questions are off-topic here. I voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

I all honesty, looking at the picture above, I'd still be keeping those tires for a while.  Your tread looks pretty good still and appears to exceed the minimum tread of 3mm.  Below is a professional opinion that I found informative while researching your question.

https://www.rightturn.com/tire-guide/cracked-tires/

Tires are created with rubber compounds that contain antidegradants such as waxes, antioxidants, or antiozonants. These help protect against ozone, oxygen, heat, and other causes of degradation that can lead to your tires cracking. These protectants don't work as well when the tires remain stationary for long periods of time. Taking a few extra strolls around town in a car you don't usually drive can help maintain its tires.

Sometimes tire sidewall cracks are actually caused by the tire scraping against the curb. Be careful when parking so that you don't damage your tires. If you clean your tires or want to use any sort of protectant, make sure that the chemicals are safe for use on tires. Cleaners that are too harsh can actually strip away the protective compounds that are designed to help prevent tire cracking.

If you're noticing tire cracking on a tire that's only a few year old, the cause may be a manufacturing defect. This is rare these days, but you should visit your local dealership so they can inspect your tires for you.

Tire cracks can allow the underlying structures within a tire to become exposed. As the structural integrity of the tire worsens, the risk of a blowout increases. A blowout, or tire failure, leads to a less responsive vehicle or possibly even a complete loss of vehicle control. And a tire blowout at highway speeds would create an immediate emergency situation.

Superficial tire sidewall cracking may not be an immediate safety concern, but sometimes cracks in tires that seem minor can get worse in no time. Severely cracked tires must be replaced.

Comment: Just showed your picture to my resident 'expert' who says your tire is likely shot.  Here is a link that will tell you why.  Once the tire starts cracking between the treads like that it can blow out in a week or a year, but they really are not safe.             
                                                                                                       
https://evanstire.com/stop-rot-need-know-tire-dry-rot/

Comment: Aw, not good news. Thanks, man. On Friday I've sent the message to the producer of the tires as well. I'll post it when they'll answer.

Comment: @ Landeeyo, I felt pretty bad about the first answer as it wasn't completely accurate.  I **would** keep driving on it.  I would not recommend it to anyone else.  Bad girl  :)